# Email Tracking Results not populating

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We did a Marketing Cloud Connect configuration on a new customer project and came across an issue we've never seen before and none of the usual integration fixes work:

- Sends from Marketing Cloud to SFDC records work fine (synchronization also works)
- Tracking is not populated back to Salesforce. **It doesn't even create Email send records**.
- When we try to initiate a send from within Salesforce we get the following error:
  [image]
- the integration log shows exactly the same:

  *****2020-01-21 17:02:01.897|EXCEPTION|Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, record type missing for: Email Send: []
- We checked record types: **All 3 record types are available** and the connector user has **full access** to those
- Support also hasn't been helpful beyond the standard steps we already tried.

Has anyone seen this before or even knows what can be done?

Thanks a lot!
Stephan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi it seems a know issue:
did you go through this url, I think yes 
Marketing Cloud Connect integrated sends failing after installing package for the first time:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003fmbQAA

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just checked and indeed, this is the correct solution. Marked as solved. I didn't see it in my known issues slack feed because I was on holiday at the time ;)

Comment: No Problem! Happy to help